# How i can comit and push with GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions, push

I am trying to push the changes that are made from the action, but it always throws an error.
I already tried to use a token with all permissions, and it still doesn't work.

This is what i have in github atcions:

```
- name: Commit and push changes
      env:
        ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACCESS_TOKEN }}
      run: |
        git config --global user.name "Polareti"
        git config --global user.email "myemail@gmail.com"
        git add Investimentos.xlsx
        git commit -m "Atualizar arquivo com novos valores [skip ci]"
        git remote set-url origin https://github.com/Polareti/Excel-Automation.git
        git push origin main
```

and this is the error:
[image: error]

Comment: How do you setup the ACCESS_TOKEN?

Comment: First of all, I created a personal token with repro permissions. After that, I went to my repository, clicked on 'Settings', and created secrets and variables in the Actions section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to commit and push with this code

```
name: Commit and push

on: 
    workflow_dispatch

permissions:
    contents: write

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - run: |
          date > generated.txt
          git config user.name github-actions
          git config user.email github-actions@github.com
          git add .
          git commit -m "generated"
          git push
```